# How do I write to the Windows registry with JNA winreg?

Tags: java, windows, registry, jna

I'm looking for a way to write to the Windows registry with Java.

I went to https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md, and I got the hello world test to work. Which shows me that the library was referenced correctly and works. I don't see any tests or examples in the download for the registry for the winreg class. The JNA javadoc does not make sense for me to even create an example.

Here is a link to [the JNA Javadoc](http://twall.github.com/jna/3.4.1/javadoc/).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Advapi32Util.registrySetIntValue(WinReg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 
                "Software\\Adobe\\Acrobat Reader\\10.0\\Privileged", "bProtectedMode", 0);
            }
}
```

Comment: Please try to turn this into a question. You said you've run the hello world program. So explain the first way that what you want to do differs from that. Then show what you tried, what you got and what you expected. Then ask "How do I make it do what I expected?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a helper class, `Advapi32Util` in the JNA platform JAR.  You might want to look at the [registryCreateKey()](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32Util.html#registryCreateKey-com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.HKEY-java.lang.String-) method, as well as the other registry manipulation methods in this class.

I also found a really simple example use [here](http://code.dblock.org/jna-accessing-windows-registry-from-java).

Comment: Read it and figured it out, I'll edit the answer in to my post. Thanks!